# How many Olympic games do we need for 8 teams to never play the same team or same game twice?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

We are hosting a backyard olympics. We have 8 teams. We want to ensure that every team plays each other once (no more) and that no one plays the same game twice. How many games do we need and what would the rotation/schedule look like?

Comment: With $8$ teams there are at most four games going on at any one time. Do you want a schedule where four games always start simultaneously, or do you have time to play the games one by one? Also, for inspiration on how to count the total number of games, you can look up the ideas behind the [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) (It's not what you are looking for, but it's a well-known result, and the same counting ideas apply here).

Comment: What constitutes "same game"? Are the plays always head-to-head? Or are there plays with more or less than two teams? I think you should be more clear and not rely on other magically having the same idea of the problem that you have.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. We would like to have 4 games with two teams competing each other (always head-to-head) in each happening at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

See this as a [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) between $8$ vertices, with each of the $28$ edges coloured and the $7$ edges coming into a vertex have different colours.  What is the minimum number of colours?

The [chromatic index](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Chromatic_index) of a complete graph with $n$ vertices is $n$ when $n$ is odd, while it is $n-1$ when $n$ is even.  So here the answer is $8-1=7$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Complete-edge-coloring.svg) illustrates a particular solution with

[image]